# Converting value of a term to an atom

Tags: prolog

I appologise in advance if any of my terminology is off, its been a few years since I've touch Prolog and I decided to try and dust off my prolog cap and have another explore around of it.

I'll dive straight into the code and stumble my way through the description of the problem afterwards. This code isn't the exact subject matter of my situation.

```
mammal :- true.
reptile :- true.

animals_that_are(_,_) :- 
    write('Not found!'), 
    nl, 
    false.

animals_that_are(mammal, L) :- 
    L = [lion, elephant, dog].

animals_that_are(reptile, L) :- 
    L = [lizard, turtle].

does_animal_belong_to_group(Species, Group) :-
    animals_that_are(Group, Animals),
    member(Species, Animals).
```

So the basic problem is that when calling `does_animal_belong_to_group(lion, mammal)`, the text Not Found! is displayed and fails, suggesting to me, that the atoms mammal and lion are being converted to terms and thus don't associate with their respective rules.

When I call the two rules directly, I do get the expected result

```
animals_that_are(reptile, L).
L = [lizard, turtle].
```

Is there a way that an atom can be passed through a term and then the atom re-extracted in this situation or am I tackling this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing more complicated than necessary:

```
animals_that_are(mammal, [lion, elephant, dog]).
animals_that_are(reptile, [lizard, turtle]).

does_animal_belong_to_group(Animal, Group) :-
    animals_that_are(Group, Animals),
    member(Animal, Animals).

?- does_animal_belong_to_group(lion, mammal).
true ;
false.
```

Also, I would change the *style* of those facts, tentatively, the predicate naming should reflect the positions of arguments:

```
animals_group([lion, elephant, dog], mammal).
```

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. What I was doing did seem complicated, and knew that I was kludging things up a bit, as its been a while since I even touched a none procedural language. Thanks for the recommendation and explanation!

Comment: those initials `mammal :- true.` suggest that you're trying something *much more* complicated. Eventually, feel free to follow up the question...

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure if its necessary or not, but I'm actually using it to act as a *declaration* of sorts for the atoms. However, as I'm reading through some of my old uni notes it seems as if I don't actually need to pre-declare things.